# How to add Google Play store on a custom device of AVD?

Tags: android-virtual-device

[image]

I'm trying to have a particular install of Android to test one of my clients claim (she has a bug with Chrome on her phone, that I can't myself replicate)

So I want to create a device that is the same as her phone model, a Samsung Galaxy S5. Thing is, AVD won't let me have the Google Play Store on a custom hardware created.

Is there a way to add the playstore to a device?

Its weird because the screenshot given is before even I select an Android Build, so what is preventing my hardware from being compatible with the playstore? Even cloning one that already exists with Play Store seemingly desactivates it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't add google play to a custom device, instead you could just install devices that already have google play.